# Wan as usb in openwrt

Tags: usb, openwrt, wan

I have an adsl modem Zte zxdsl 831 series and internet usb port from it. When I put this usb into my windows xp laptop then internet appears in laptop. But I want to connect modem to my router instead (asus wl-500gp v2 with openwrt) and tehtering in over wifi to laptop and mobile devices. But I don't know what tecnology is used zte modem to tethering internet over usb and can't setting up my router to use usb as a wan.

Comment: sounds like your isp has locked your service to a single mac address you will have to contact them to confirm

Comment: No, I just don't know how to configure my router to use usb as a wan

Comment: How can you dismiss my comment?  Are you sure OpenWRT even supports what your trying to do?